# Add after_create filter to a model inside a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

So there's this model that exists inside of modules in a gem. The model is called `AccessToken` and the structure is as follows

```
module Devise
  module OAuth2Providable    
    class AccessToken
      ... # Class stuff
    end
  end
end
```

I need to somehow money-patch an `after_create` filter into this class, from inside my own app. I've tried things such as

```
# app/models/devise/oauth2_providable/access_token.rb
module Devise
  module OAuth2Providable    
    class AccessToken

      after_filter do 
        # My block
      end

      ... # Class stuff
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried

```
# app/models/devise/oauth2_providable/access_token.rb
module Devise
  module OAuth2Providable    
    class AccessToken << self

      after_filter do 
        # My block
      end

      ... # Class stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Among other variations. I even asked my boss, and he did not have an answer :/.

Answer (score 0):

I saw these codes recently:
https://github.com/ledermann/unread/blob/master/lib/unread/base.rb#L12

Is there any help?